# MediaRecord Lossless/Compression-Less Format

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I am using MediaRecorder in an android application. I'd like to make recordings in a lossless, compression-less format. A WAV file would be a good example, but it doesn't have to be exactly that. Is there some option to specify this type of format?

Comment: I am currently looking for something similar :) when I know more I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell now, it's not possible yet. You can use Androids AudioRecord class instead.

[Here](http://i-liger.com/article/android-wav-audio-recording) is a complete example of how 44100 sampling rate with 16 bit / sample can be recorded. So far I didn't manage to record better via phonegap & android :)

A lossless format like PCM that could be saved to a container like AIFF, MP4, Matroska, Ogg or WAV. But I don't see android offering these settings. That's why in the tutorial I posted here you create your own wave file. I tried and got it running in the end, after adjusting it to my needs.